# March at the end of Jean Michel Jarre concert

Tags: identify-this-song, instrumental

At the end of Jean Michel Jarre's *Equinoxe VII*, in the album *Les Concerts en Chine*, after the applause, a [march or anthem](https://youtu.be/YR45QzmxuUc?t=9m14s) can be heard. Does anyone know its name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a Chinese military march called the [Farewell March](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSoA9AuF5KI&index=35&list=PLlO0ckvbly9XD-2deWfpqKfSTRUifmuKQ), (欢送进行曲). There are another 64 in the linked playlist if you feel like listening to more.

*Equinox VII* ends the second part of the 1981 China concert which also includes the arrangement of a traditional Chinese song performed with the Beijing Symphony Orchestra, *Jonques De Pêcheurs Au Crépuscule*.

So I guess this must be the orchestra saying goodbye.